# "Все(,) что угодно"

Tags: пунктуация

Извините, если вопрос уже был (поиском не нашелся). Нужна ли запятая после "все" в выражении "все(,) что угодно"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, запятая нужна.   
Почему вы сомневаетесь — понятно. Действительно есть такие предложения, где конструкция *"что угодно"* не отделяется запятой. В этих предложениях *"что угодно"* можно заменить одним словом. Например: *"Дома ей позволяли делать что угодно (=всё)"*. Думаю, в вашем предложении эту конструкцию можно рассмотреть с двух сторон: в качестве обычной придаточной, соединяющуюся с главной союзом *"что"*, и в качестве уточнения: *"что угодно"* уточняет слово *"всё"*. Хотя второй вариант мне кажется сомнительным.

Answer (score 9):

Если **все что угодно** является частью сложноподчиненного предложения, то запятая нужна, например: Сотрудник выполняет *все, что угодно* начальству. Если **все что угодно** является самостоятельным цельным выражением, то запятая не нужна: Купить можно *все_ что угодно*.