# Всё, что угодно – синтаксическая роль?

Tags: синтаксис

*Она предлагала ему всё, **что угодно**.*

*всё* – дополнение?

*что угодно* – придаточное относительное?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Она предлагала ему всё, что угодно.

Правильно [без запятой](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_117): *Она предлагала ему **всё что угодно**.*

Здесь ***всё что угодно*** -- дополнение.

Comment: наверное это погрешность переводчика, потому что запятая стоит на самом деле в книге. Slava, скажите пожалуйста: а если можно было бы поставить там глагол, тогда это было бы придаточное? если вот так было бы: Она предлагала ему всё, что ему БЫЛО угодно (деньги, драгоценности). или так по-русски не говорят?

Comment: _Anonym: ...или так по-русски не говорят?_ === Говорят. === _...всё, что ему БЫЛО угодно._  При распространении оборота "всё что угодно" дополнением будет слово "всё", а "что ему БЫЛО угодно" --  придаточным.

Comment: ajá поняла, спасибо большое!!! =)

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что "что угодно" является неполным придаточным. "Запятой отделяются неполные или близкие к неполным придаточные предложения, например: Он не понял, в чем дело; Рад помочь, чем смогу; Запомнил, чему учили; Люди знают, что делают; Сделайте, что нужно; Могу предоставить все, что угодно; Он понимает, что к чему; Садитесь, где свободно; Ругали все, кому не лень; Встретимся, знаете где; Болтал, не знаю что. Но: Делай что хочешь и т.п., см. §114, п. 1." 
[Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ
М.: ЧеРо, 1999](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Она предлагала ему всё что угодно (лишь бы он уехал).

Следует отличать **устойчивое выражение "всё что угодно"** (любой предмет) от СПП, где целостность устойчивого выражения нарушается.

**Примеры**

Зачем это было, если он мог **всё что угодно** сыграть по слуху? Конечно, присниться человеку может **всё что угодно.**

Сравнить: Он напишет вам **всё что угодно** (устойчивое выражение).  Он напишет  **всё, что вам будет угодно** (СПП с местоименно-определительным придаточным).

Вопрос уже обсуждался:

["Все(,) что угодно"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13460/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)